# Deploying on Heroku using Node.js application fails

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, heroku

I'm following the book *Getting MEAN with Mongo, Express, Angular and Node.js* and I'm trying to deploy my application to Heroku. I already did it but can't access the live URL, cause I get an application error. I don't know what is happening and why it didn't work, I followed all the concepts in the book.

**Here is the tail log from the cmd**

```
    2016-10-11T19:51:45.814527+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy d98fd8a by filipecosta_10@h
otmail.com
2016-10-11T19:51:45.814527+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by filipecosta_
10@hotmail.com
2016-10-11T19:51:47.335153+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started

2016-10-11T19:51:47.335158+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finishe
d
2016-10-11T19:51:48.026456+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `n
pm start`
2016-10-11T19:51:50.965855+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-10-11T19:51:50.965871+00:00 app[web.1]: > loc8r@0.0.0 start /app
2016-10-11T19:51:50.965872+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2016-10-11T19:51:50.965873+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-10-11T19:51:51.158696+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:327
2016-10-11T19:51:51.158699+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2016-10-11T19:51:51.158699+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2016-10-11T19:51:51.158700+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-10-11T19:51:51.158701+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../contr
ollers/main'
2016-10-11T19:51:51.158702+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFile
name (module.js:325:15)
2016-10-11T19:51:51.158703+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (modul
e.js:276:25)
2016-10-11T19:51:51.158703+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:35
3:17)
2016-10-11T19:51:51.158704+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:
12:17)
2016-10-11T19:51:51.158705+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app
_server/routes/index.js:3:17)
2016-10-11T19:51:51.158705+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:4
09:26)
2016-10-11T19:51:51.158706+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..j
s (module.js:416:10)
2016-10-11T19:51:51.158706+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:343:3
2)
2016-10-11T19:51:51.158707+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (modul
e.js:300:12)
2016-10-11T19:51:51.158708+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:35
3:17)
2016-10-11T19:51:51.167422+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-10-11T19:51:51.174247+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bi
n/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-10-11T19:51:51.173815+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-95-generic
2016-10-11T19:51:51.174531+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v4.5.0
2016-10-11T19:51:51.174888+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v2.15.11
2016-10-11T19:51:51.175128+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-10-11T19:51:51.175398+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! loc8r@0.0.0 start: `node .
/bin/www`
2016-10-11T19:51:51.175544+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-10-11T19:51:51.175660+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2016-10-11T19:51:51.175761+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the loc8r@0.0.0
start script 'node ./bin/www'.
2016-10-11T19:51:51.175878+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a prob
lem with the loc8r package,
2016-10-11T19:51:51.176070+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this
fails on your system:
2016-10-11T19:51:51.176164+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
2016-10-11T19:51:51.176253+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on
 how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-10-11T19:51:51.175977+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-10-11T19:51:51.176393+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs loc8r
2016-10-11T19:51:51.176495+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available
, you can get their info via:
2016-10-11T19:51:51.176593+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2016-10-11T19:51:51.176685+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls loc8r
2016-10-11T19:51:51.176781+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional
 logging output above.
2016-10-11T19:51:51.180051+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-10-11T19:51:51.180327+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-10-11T19:51:51.180221+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the followi
ng file with any support request:
2016-10-11T19:51:51.279651+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2016-10-11T19:51:51.280869+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2016-10-11T19:51:51.268892+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-10-11T19:51:52.894691+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `n
pm start`
2016-10-11T19:51:55.200670+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-10-11T19:51:55.200685+00:00 app[web.1]: > loc8r@0.0.0 start /app
2016-10-11T19:51:55.200685+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2016-10-11T19:51:55.200686+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-10-11T19:51:55.471950+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:327
2016-10-11T19:51:55.471963+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2016-10-11T19:51:55.471963+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2016-10-11T19:51:55.471967+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-10-11T19:51:55.471967+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../contr
ollers/main'
2016-10-11T19:51:55.471968+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFile
name (module.js:325:15)
2016-10-11T19:51:55.471968+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (modul
e.js:276:25)
2016-10-11T19:51:55.471969+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:35
3:17)
2016-10-11T19:51:55.471969+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:
12:17)
2016-10-11T19:51:55.471970+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app
_server/routes/index.js:3:17)
2016-10-11T19:51:55.471971+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:4
09:26)
2016-10-11T19:51:55.471971+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..j
s (module.js:416:10)
2016-10-11T19:51:55.471972+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:343:3
2)
2016-10-11T19:51:55.471972+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (modul
e.js:300:12)
2016-10-11T19:51:55.471973+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:35
3:17)
2016-10-11T19:51:55.481097+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-10-11T19:51:55.487850+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-95-generic
2016-10-11T19:51:55.488249+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bi
n/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-10-11T19:51:55.489769+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v4.5.0
2016-10-11T19:51:55.489771+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v2.15.11
2016-10-11T19:51:55.489771+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-10-11T19:51:55.489772+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! loc8r@0.0.0 start: `node .
/bin/www`
2016-10-11T19:51:55.489773+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-10-11T19:51:55.489897+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2016-10-11T19:51:55.490059+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the loc8r@0.0.0
start script 'node ./bin/www'.
2016-10-11T19:51:55.490228+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a prob
lem with the loc8r package,
2016-10-11T19:51:55.490384+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-10-11T19:51:55.490534+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this
fails on your system:
2016-10-11T19:51:55.490692+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
2016-10-11T19:51:55.490844+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on
 how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-10-11T19:51:55.491004+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs loc8r
2016-10-11T19:51:55.491156+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available
, you can get their info via:
2016-10-11T19:51:55.491308+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2016-10-11T19:51:55.491457+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls loc8r
2016-10-11T19:51:55.491613+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional
 logging output above.
2016-10-11T19:51:55.495210+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-10-11T19:51:55.495590+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-10-11T19:51:55.495442+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the followi
ng file with any support request:
2016-10-11T19:51:55.601435+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2016-10-11T19:51:55.580900+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-10-11T19:57:39.619644+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=fast-plains-12113.herokuapp.com request_id=6d440a
4e-993d-4676-ae41-939426ff1ffd fwd="2.83.58.24" dyno= connect= service= status=5
03 bytes=
2016-10-11T19:57:40.240525+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fast-plains-12113.herokuapp.com reques
t_id=c5caca51-92c0-4532-b56c-6f060cd39634 fwd="2.83.58.24" dyno= connect= servic
e= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-11T20:00:42.624338+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=fast-plains-12113.herokuapp.com request_id=ef7dc9
6d-920b-4a4c-ae7a-9ccb584b1682 fwd="2.83.58.24" dyno= connect= service= status=5
03 bytes=
2016-10-11T20:00:42.771815+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fast-plains-12113.herokuapp.com reques
t_id=50598f55-4a3e-4b30-ac54-e77a722fb839 fwd="2.83.58.24" dyno= connect= servic
e= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-11T20:03:25.808113+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=fast-plains-12113.herokuapp.com request_id=9e2da8
b4-e936-4812-93a7-378ec78606f8 fwd="2.83.58.24" dyno= connect= service= status=5
03 bytes=
2016-10-11T20:03:25.961352+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fast-plains-12113.herokuapp.com reques
t_id=5d95a945-dcfa-4248-981d-11ce2f764b56 fwd="2.83.58.24" dyno= connect= servic
e= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: It looks like your `bin/www` script is unable to find the `controllers/main` file(s). It's currently referencing them a level "up" from your current, working directory (the project root, which is where `npm start` is/should be running from). I expect that your `npm start` (which is `node ./bin/www`) has a controllers directory in the root of the project, making it two levels up, not one (relative to the `www`). I would try changing your `bin/www` reference from `../controllers/main` to `../../controllers/main`, assuming that's correct. If not, post back the folder structure of your files.

Comment: didnt worked :/ i am a beginner working with heroku this is kinda strange for newbies

Comment: Everyone starts somewhere. Can you edit your question to show the project folder structure? (either as a screen shot or output of [`tree -d`](http://www.explainshell.com/explain?cmd=tree+-d))

Comment: see here https://github.com/FilipeCosta/loc8r

Comment: I see it. It's actually a reference in your `app_server/routes/index.js` which is looking for `../controllers/main`, but your [controllers dir is capitalized](https://github.com/FilipeCosta/loc8r/tree/d98fd8a32dd9d588f8ca0612af42b571a461e104/app_server). Either un-capitalize "controllers" or change [the reference](https://github.com/FilipeCosta/loc8r/blob/d98fd8a32dd9d588f8ca0612af42b571a461e104/app_server/routes/index.js#L3)

Comment: yeah got that error, i change it didnt worked, then i tried to change to ../../controllers/main   like before still nothing :S

Comment: Well, after cloning, install, and run on local, it seems to run fine. After reviewing [heroku's page on getting started with node](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#define-a-procfile), I can't help but wonder if you changed your `Procfile` to use `node bin/www` instead of `npm start` if that would clear thing up.

Comment: still nothing, thank you for your help, dont understand what i am doing wrong :S

Comment: This feels a bit strange. I've occasionally run into a situation where typing in the relative path seems to cause issues and instead settle on [using `path.join`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path) to preclude the mess.

Comment: what do you mean, i just run heroku open

Comment: it still cant find the controller have no idea friend, thank you for your help :D

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't be more help; it seemed so obvious at first. :-/